# Asp.net mvc core TagHelpers not working Suddenly after migration

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

Have a project with Entity Framework Core and asp.net mvc core. 
This project was working correctly. But when removed migration folder from Data layer and then update DB, suddenly showed me an error like this :

> Cannot override the 'href' attribute for . An  with a specified 'href' must not have attributes starting with 'asp-route-' or an 'asp-action', 'asp-controller', 'asp-area', 'asp-route', 'asp-protocol', 'asp-host', 'asp-fragment', 'asp-page' or 'asp-page-handler' attribute.

Actually I want to open a view with `<a asp-action="..." ...>` from home controller to another controller in a area. please help me.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem. If you have `asp-route="@something.Id"` in your project, modify it to `asp-route-id="@something.Id"`.